# BootStrap Multiple Active Nav Tabs Issue

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

There are two sets of `<ul>` elements in my page. It's working, but now the issue is there will be two tabs active at the same time. Let's say I click `tab-3` and then `tab-a`. The tab will switch to `tab-a` but now both of them would be in the active state. How can I fix this?

```
<div>
  <div class="hr-text hr-text-left m-t-2 m-b-1"><h6><strong>List 1</strong></h6></div>
    <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
      <li role="presentation" class="active"><a data-target="#tab-1" data-toggle="tab">1</a></li>
      <li role="presentation"><a data-target="#tab-2" data-toggle="tab">2</a></li>
      <li role="presentation"><a data-target="#tab-3" data-toggle="tab">3</a></li>
    </ul>

  <div class="hr-text hr-text-left m-t-2 m-b-1"><h6><strong>List 2</strong></h6></div>
    <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
      <li role="presentation" class=""><a data-target="#tab-a" data-toggle="tab">A</a></li>
      <li role="presentation"><a data-target="#tab-b" data-toggle="tab">B</a></li>
      <li role="presentation"><a data-target="#tab-c" data-toggle="tab">C</a></li>
    </ul>

  <div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane" id="tab-1"><h1>1</h1></div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="tab-2"><h1>2</h1></div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="tab-3"><h1>3</h1></div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="tab-a"><h1>A</h1></div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="tab-b"><h1>B</h1></div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="tab-c"><h1>C</h1></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change your html as below:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div>
  <div class="hr-text hr-text-left m-t-2 m-b-1">
    <h6><strong>List 1</strong></h6>
  </div>
  <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
    <li role="presentation" class="active"><a data-target="#tab-1" data-toggle="tab">1</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a data-target="#tab-2" data-toggle="tab">2</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a data-target="#tab-3" data-toggle="tab">3</a></li>

    <li><h6><strong>List 2</strong></h6></li>

    <li role="presentation" class=""><a data-target="#tab-a" data-toggle="tab">A</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a data-target="#tab-b" data-toggle="tab">B</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a data-target="#tab-c" data-toggle="tab">C</a></li>
  </ul>

  <div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane" id="tab-1">
      <h1>1</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="tab-2">
      <h1>2</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="tab-3">
      <h1>3</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="tab-a">
      <h1>A</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="tab-b">
      <h1>B</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="tab-c">
      <h1>C</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Better approach than mine, I would prefer this.

Comment: This answer is not useful for future readers (like myself). Would be helpful to add an explanation as to what changes you made to the html so that we don't have to hunt them down and carefully inspect ourselves

Comment: Can anyone say what is the solution.?

Answer (score 1):

[BootStrap Reference](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs-events)

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kv8yLL08/)

To make tab inactive, *css* class is removed:`curActiveNav.removeClass('active')`

If there is API way to mark inactive, that would be preferred.

```js
$(document).ready( function(){

 function unactiveOther( source ){
   // Source element
    var $sourceTabLink = $(source),
     $sourceTab = $sourceTabLink.parent('li');
        
   // wrapper element
    var activeNav = $sourceTab.closest('.multipleTabNav')
     // find all active
     .find('[role=presentation].active');
    
    activeNav.each( function(){
     
      // Get current active nav
      var curActiveNav = $(this),
       curActiveNavLink = curActiveNav.find('a');
      
      // inactive unmatched nav
      if ( curActiveNavLink.attr('data-target') !== $sourceTabLink.attr('data-target') ){
       curActiveNav.removeClass('active');
      }
      
    })
  }
  
  $('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
    //console.log( e.target ); // newly activated tab
    //console.log( e.relatedTarget );// previous active tab
    unactiveOther( e.target );
  })
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="multipleTabNav">
  <div class="hr-text hr-text-left m-t-2 m-b-1"><h6><strong>List 1</strong></h6></div>
    <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
      <li role="presentation" class="active"><a data-target="#tab-1" data-toggle="tab">1</a></li>
      <li role="presentation"><a data-target="#tab-2" data-toggle="tab">2</a></li>
      <li role="presentation"><a data-target="#tab-3" data-toggle="tab">3</a></li>
    </ul>

  <div class="hr-text hr-text-left m-t-2 m-b-1"><h6><strong>List 2</strong></h6></div>
    <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
      <li role="presentation" class=""><a data-target="#tab-a" data-toggle="tab">A</a></li>
      <li role="presentation"><a data-target="#tab-b" data-toggle="tab">B</a></li>
      <li role="presentation"><a data-target="#tab-c" data-toggle="tab">C</a></li>
    </ul>

  <div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane" id="tab-1"><h1>1</h1></div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="tab-2"><h1>2</h1></div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="tab-3"><h1>3</h1></div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="tab-a"><h1>A</h1></div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="tab-b"><h1>B</h1></div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="tab-c"><h1>C</h1></div>      
  </div>
    
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for you input, appreciate it